# How to crawl with breadth-first search using Scrapy (Python3)?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I want to run the crawler as breadth-first search.
So, I wrote the following code.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http   import Request

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/a']

    def parse(self, response):
        next_a = response.css('.next::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_a:
            yield Request(next_a, callback=self.parse, priority = 3)

        for b in response.css('.b::attr("href")'):
            yield Request(b, callback=self.parse_b, priority = 2)

    def parse_b(self, response):
        pass
```

I am hoping that this crawler will move as follows.
a1, a2, a3, ..., an, b1, b2, b3, ...., bn

But actually it will be like this.
a1, b1, b2, ...., b_n1, a2, b_n1+1, b_n1+2, ....

How can I run as expected?

Answer (score 11):

Quoting from [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order)

> ### Does Scrapy crawl in breadth-first or depth-first order?
>
> By default, Scrapy uses a [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) queue for storing pending requests, which
> basically means that it crawls in [DFO order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). This order is more convenient
> in most cases. If you do want to crawl in true [BFO order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), you can do it by
> setting the following settings:
>
> ```
> DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
> SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
> SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
> ```